# ¿Que es un dato char?un dato char puede ser un valor numerico?

Tags: c++, c

Que es in dato char, es que no se si puedo darle como valor un numero.

Comment: Respuesta corta: `char` ya es un tipo integral. [¿Por qué no leer al respecto?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm)

Answer (score 2):

En general el tipo `char` está orientado a almacenar un "[caracter](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car%C3%A1cter_(tipo_de_dato))" (unidad de texto: normalmente una letra o dígito o signo de puntuación o espacio o...). En la práctica, lo que se almacena es el código númerico del caracter en cierta codificación. En C, el `char` se corresponde a un `byte` (el cual a su vez se corresponde -no estrictamente hablando, pero sí prácticamente hablando- a un octeto = 8 bits).

De modo que, sí, en C, en la práctica, un C un char se puede  tratar como un número de 8 bits - puedes usarlo para almacenar un número, puedes hacer aritmética con él. Ejemplo

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   char c1,c2;
   c1 = 'a';
   c2 = 97;
   if(c1==c2) printf("iguales\n");
   else       printf("distintos\n");
   c1 = c1 + 3;
   printf("c1 como caracter: %c como numero: %d\n",c1,(int)c1);
   return 0;
}
```

Imprime

```
iguales
c1 como caracter: d como numero: 100
```

Pero

- Tienes que tener cuidado con no excederte en el rango (sólo son 8 bits)
- Si haces aritmética y comparaciones debes aclararte si estás trabajando con `signed char` (rango: -128 a 127) o `unsigned char` (rango: 0 a 255)
- No es bueno mezclar los conceptos (textos vs números). Si tu `char` representa un caracter textual, entonces no es bueno asignarle un número, porque eso implicaría atarte a una determinada codificación.

En general, conviene mejor usar `int_8` u `uint_8` si quieres almacenar números de 8 bits.

Comment: Pero tengo un problema es que yo hice una clase, con atributos tipos char pero en el main solo funciona con datos tipos int

Comment: Que quieres que te diga... postea el detalle de tu clase y los errores que te tira

Answer (score 0):

Buenas,

El tipo de datos `char` corresponde en c++ a caracter o cadena de caracteres, en respuesta a tu pregunta,  **si podrías asignarle un numero, pero te lo tomaría como un caracter**, no como valor numérico, si necesitas tener variables de tipo numero, utiliza `int` para números enteros o `float` para numeros reales.

Saludos, espero te ayude mi pregunta, igual te dejo un material de un curso muy bueno en youtube que te podría servir.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eoOhncKQdoM

Answer (score 0):

Claro que puedes darle un valor númerico, pero recuerda algo importante, -128 a 127, te recomiendo usarlo como `unsigned` en caso de que no requieras númericos negativos y así tendrás alcanze de <255.

Un ejemplo de código sería:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        unsigned char i;
        for (i=0; i<255; i++) {
                printf("%i\n", i);
        };
        return 0;
}
```

En caso de que sea menor te recomiendo usar char, ya que ocupa menos bytes, pero si requires más grande usa `int`, `long int`, etc.

Igual podrás sumarlo entre sí como el operador `+=`, siempre y cuando ocupes una longitud baja, y en caso de que quieras concatenarlo en una cadena usa `sprintf(buf, "%i", i);` (ocuparás un array o `malloc()` de `stdlib.h` para almacenar datos).

En realidad su uso si es totalmente compatible con númericos siempre y cuando si lo deseas concatenar no uses `%c` porque en ese casoe estarías usándolo como cadena, si la función ocupa `int` solo usa `(int)valor_char` para convertir el dato, aunque en dicho caso si es mucho mejor usar un dato tipo `int`.

Te recomiendo esta página para aprender más a lujos de detalles C: https://elrincondelc.com.

Sinceramente, no sé como dicen que es obligatorio usar `int` en números, yo soy parte del desarrollo de un lenguaje de programación y para números cortos siempre uso `char`, es más ahorrativo, aunque si tu script es pequeño, no te preocupes por muchos detalles de memoria, ya que no habrá demasiada diferencia en el perfomance (velocidad), en dicho caso de que quieras ver más detalles de errores de memoria en tus script, te recomiendo usar Valgrind, te ayudará a evitar problemas de memoria.

¡Mucha suerte!